# How do I use getclassbyelemenentnames?

Tags: javascript

So currently I have this bit of code:

```
function bgchanger(color){
  document.getElementById("headwrapper").style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.getElementById("footerwrapper").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Accompanied by this HTML:

```
<div id="blue" style="cursor: pointer" onClick="bgchanger('blue')"></div>
```

It works well for changing the color of divs on click. However, it's notably inefficient. Rather than identifying two divs by Element Id, I should be calling them by a shared class. But I'm a little unclear on exactly how I would arrange a document.getElementsByClassName since it's apparently arranged differently than the ID method.

Comment: Why do you think it's inefficient? `getElementById()` is crazy fast. I'd bet that selecting by class name will be slower.

Comment: But if you mean that you have lots to select, and don't want to repeat lots of code, then yes, a class is better. So if you're asking how to select by class, just Google it. It isn't like it's a big secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean inefficient to code, since at runtime `getElementById()` will be fast. But as you imply, your JS would be neater if it could do this sort of thing by class rather than having a bunch of hard-coded ids. Indeed if your JS no longer needs to use ids you can omit them from your html too (unless they're used in your stylesheet).

So, [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a list, so just loop through it:

```
function bgchanger(color){
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KNxBV/

Update with cookie monster's suggestion:

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead of `getElementsByClassName()` - it has slightly better browser support:

```
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
    // other code as above. Note the . ---^
```

Updated demo: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KNxBV/1/

Comment: Or `querySelectorAll()` for IE8 support.

Comment: thanks for this. it seems from all the examples i've looked at that ` for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)` or at least some variation of it is the driving method for getting an element by class.

Comment: Yep, you have to do some kind of loop. (Even libraries like jQuery that let you write your code without a loop will use a loop internally.) Although instead of updating the `color` directly you can define some classes based on a hierarchical structure and just add and remove the classes from the parent element in the hierarchy - that way you don't change the individual elements from JS, just the parent.

Comment: If you're doing to do things to the _class_ in the loop, remember, the list given by `getElementsByClassName` is **live** and so may change during the loop. For this reason I normally try to loop down where the reference is live.